# Spring-Batch: writing a Partitioner for a unknown number of partitions

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, bioinformatics, partitioning

I'm learning spring-batch.  I'm currently working with biological data that look like this:

```
interface Variant {
  public String getChromosome();
  public int getPosition();
  public Set<String> getGenes();
}
```

(A **Variant** is a position on the genome which may overlap somes genes).

I've already written some [Itemreaders/Itemwriters](https://github.com/lindenb/jvarkit/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/lindenb/jvarkit/tools/springbatch.)

Now I would like to run some analysis **per gene**. Thus I would like to split my workflow for each gene (gene1, gene2,... geneN) to do some statistics about all the variants linked to one gene.

[image]

What is the best way to implement a [Partioner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk//apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/Partitioner.html) for this (is it the correct class anyway ?) ? All the examples I've seen use some 'indexes' or a finite number of `gridSize` ? Furthermore, does the map returned by [partiton(gridsize)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk//apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/support/Partitioner.html#partition-int-) must have less than gridSize items or can I returned a 'big' map and spring-batch is able to run no more than `gridSize` jobs in parallel ? how can  join the data at the end ?

thanks

**EDIT**: or may be I should look at MultiResourceItemWriter ?

Answer (score 3):

When using Spring Batch's partitioning capabilities, there are two main classes involved, the `Partitioner` and the `PartitionHandler`.

**`Partitioner`**
The `Partitioner` interface is responsible for dividing up the data to be processed into partitions.  It has a single method `Partitioner#partition(int gridSize)` that is responsible for analyzing the data that is to be partitioned and returning a `Map` with one entry per partition.  The `gridSize` parameter is really just a piece of input into the overall calculation that can be used or ignored.  For example, if the `gridSize` is 5, I may choose to return exactly 5 partitions, I may choose to overpartition and return some multiple of 5, or I may analyze the data and realize that I only need 3 partitions and completely ignore the `gridSize` value.

**`PartionHandler`**
The `PartitionHandler` is responsible for the delegation of the partitions returned by the `Partitioner` to workers.  Within the Spring ecosystem, there are three provided `PartitionHandler` implementations, a `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` that delegates the work to threads internal to the current JVM, a `MessageChannelPartitionHandler` that delegates work to remote workers listening on some form of messaging middleware, and a `DeployerPartitionHandler` out of the Spring Cloud Task project that launches new workers dynamically to execute the provided partitions.

With all the above laid out, to answer your specific questions:

1. **What is the best way to implement a Partioner for this (is it the correct class anyway ?) ?** That typically depends on the data your partitioning and the store it's in.  Without further insights into how you are storing the gene data, I can't really comment on what the best approach is.
2. **Does the map returned by partiton(gridsize) must have less than gridSize items or can I returned a 'big' map and spring-batch is able to run no more than gridSize jobs in parallel ?** You can return as many items in the `Map` as you see fit.  As mentioned above, the `gridSize` is really meant as a guide.
3. **How can join the data at the end ?** A partitioned step is expected to have each partition processed independently of each other.  If you want some form of join at the end, you'll typically do that in a step after the partition step.

Comment: thanks for 2 and 3. For 1 I think that 'Partition' is not the correct classes I needed, I'm more looking for a kind of loop that would launch a parallele/independant job for each gene; I'm still exploring, but I still cannot find a good code sample...

Comment: If you move this to the Spring Batch Gitter channel we can discuss your use case in more depth.

Comment: I will ! (tomorrow , it's the end of the day here... )